# How to add a line break before a list or a data frame

Tags: r, line-breaks

This might be a duplicate question, but I have been looking for an answer already for quite a while and could not find anything. If I run this short piece of code and print out description and results:

```
gear_query <- 5
mtcars_subset <- mtcars[mtcars$gear == gear_query, ]

paste("Cars with", gear_query, "gears:")   ## description
print(mtcars_subset)                       ## results
```

I get this output to the console:

```
> paste("Cars with", gear_query, "gears:")
Cars with 5 gears:
> print(mtcars_subset)
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.5  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.5  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora  15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.6  0  1    5    8
```

How can I get R to print this information in one go, so that it looks like this, with nothing in between the description and the results:

```
> whatevercodethatdoesthetrick
Cars with 5 gears:
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.5  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.5  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora  15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.6  0  1    5    8
```

I tried it with cat():

```
cat("Cars with", gear_query, "gears:\n", mtcars_subset)
```

but got an error that 'list' cannot be handled by 'cat'. I also played around with paste(), but could not get it to work. Probably a pretty simple problem, but I can´t get to it ...

Comment: Wrap in a function? `print_gear_query = function(g = 5) {cat("Cars with", g, "gears:\n"); mtcars[mtcars$gear == g, ]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using knitr:

```
library(knitr)

gear_query <- 5
kable(mtcars[ mtcars$gear == gear_query, ],
      format = "pandoc",
      caption = paste("Cars with", gear_query, "gears:"))

Table: Cars with 5 gears:

                   mpg   cyl    disp    hp   drat      wt   qsec   vs   am   gear   carb
---------------  -----  ----  ------  ----  -----  ------  -----  ---  ---  -----  -----
Porsche 914-2     26.0     4   120.3    91   4.43   2.140   16.7    0    1      5      2
Lotus Europa      30.4     4    95.1   113   3.77   1.513   16.9    1    1      5      2
Ford Pantera L    15.8     8   351.0   264   4.22   3.170   14.5    0    1      5      4
Ferrari Dino      19.7     6   145.0   175   3.62   2.770   15.5    0    1      5      6
Maserati Bora     15.0     8   301.0   335   3.54   3.570   14.6    0    1      5      8
```